# Meteor.user() login issue

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am testing a restrict login function with router code below

```
var requireLogin = function() { 
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
   console.log("user not logged");
   this.next()
 } else {
   console.log("user logged");
   this.next()
 }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {except: ['home','login','about']});
```

when I try to enter restricted area like `userprofile` it ask me to log in and print `"user not logged"`
and after I successfully log in and try to access that area again. it printing both code starts with `"user not logged"` and then `"user logged"`

I want to know how to avoid this to happen? since some page become glitched when this happened.

I want it to only print `"user logged"` if I enter a restricted area page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to integrate `Meteor.loggingIn()` somewhere in your `requireLogin` function. Because, what's happening is that Meteor is still loading the user system and for every route change, it re-authenticates the user based on current session, if it exists.

```
var requireLogin = function() { 
    if(!Meteor.user()){
        if(Meteor.loggingIn()){
            this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
        }else{
            this.render('accessDenied');
        }
    }else {
        this.next();
    }
}
```

You will notice that it uses `this.loadingTemplate`. To keep this, you must also configure your routes to have a loading template. e.g.:

```
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});
```

or you could just simply swap that out with `this.render('loading');` where `'loading'` is the template name of your 'Now loading' yield/page.